# How do I exclude files from git ls-files?

Tags: git, bash

How do I list everything except markdown files? I have tried to run ls-files with the --exclude flag, but the excluded files are still shown in the output.

My git version is 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)

```
$ git ls-files
ChromeExt/read-coffee
Node/README.md
Node/web-scraping
README.md

$ git ls-files --exclude *.md
ChromeExt/read-coffee
Node/README.md
Node/web-scraping
README.md
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Git has its own way to extend glob patterns, and that includes a way to exclude files that match one pattern but not another. For example, the following will list all paths not ending in .md:

```
git ls-files -- . ':!:*.md'
```

It's important to quote the pattern, because you want git to parse it, not the shell.

And to match all files ending with `.js`, except the ones ending with `.min.js`:

```
git ls-files -- '*.js' ':!:*.min.js'
```

You can also use this with other commands, such as git grep:

```
git grep -w funcname -- '*.js' ':!:*.min.js'
```

This syntax is explained under [pathspec in gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) (or `git help glossary` or `man gitglossary`)

Comment: To ignore two file types, the following works: `git ls-files -- . ':!:*.md' . ':!:*.css'`, though it may not be the shortest way to do it.

Comment: can I exclude also folders?

Comment: @alper Sure, ignore any files inside a test dir: `':!:test/*' ':!:*/test/*'`

Comment: Too bad double negation seems not supported *(git interprets `:!!:` as if it was `:!:`)*. It would be useful to list files with specific extension in a given list of directories. Yeah, I know it could be done by repeating a `*.md` at the end of each path, but this is awkward to use, especially in scripting.

Answer (score 12):

That was [already discussed in 2010](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/ls-files-exclude-broken-td5536384.html):

> There is no indication in the man page that -x doesn't apply to -c.

Hence the addition:

> Since [b5227d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5227d80aee5173bfda6aa43a890d03110b0df26), `-x/--exclude` does not apply to cached files.
>   This is easy to miss unless you read the discussion in the `EXCLUDE PATTERNS` section. Clarify that the option applies to untracked files and direct the reader to `EXCLUDE PATTERNS`.

The [`git ls-files` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) does mentions:

```
-x <pattern>
--exclude=<pattern>
```

> Skip **untracked** files matching pattern

If your `Readme.md` is tracked, the exclude pattern won't apply.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to use the --exclude parameter
because this key is only used for skipping untracked files:

```
$ man git-ls-files

-x <pattern>, --exclude=<pattern>
       Skip untracked files matching pattern. Note that pattern is a shell wildcard pattern. See EXCLUDE PATTERNS below for more information.
```

You should just use a mask for required files

In your case (excluding *.md files):

```
$ git ls-files
example1.txt
example2.pdf
readme.md

$ git ls-files *[^.md]
example1.txt
example2.pdf
```

Comment: Partof your answer does duplicate mine, but I like the mask solution. It does work on Windows if you add double-quotes. +1 to you for the mask part.

Comment: On Mac it is working in both cases with and without quotes.
So with double-quotes will be better.
And yes sorry for dublicate, I didn't refresh page before posting

Comment: Where can one find documentation on this mask feature?

Comment: `*[^.md]` matches files that don't end in `.`, `m`, and `d`. So `readme.md` is excluded because it ends with `d`, not because it ends with `.md`.

Comment: @geirha you are totally right, that was my mistake at regexp, which in that corner case worked fine and I will kepp that at my answer as example for my point. I hope people will see your comment with explanation.

Comment: It's 2020, I support anything to do with using a mask.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a grep reverse match `-v`?

```sh
git ls-files | grep -v -E "\.md$"
```