# git ls-files exclude files in a directory

Tags: git, git-ls-files

I'm trying to run `git ls-files` and exclude a specific directory from it. Does the `--exclude` flag only exclude file patterns, and not directories?

`git ls-files -x */util/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) says, `-x` takes a *pattern* argument, so it only excludes patterns.

But Git only *stores* files: "directories" or "folders" only exist in the imagination—and, alas, reality—of your computer's operating system, not in Git.  Git just has *files* named `foo/util/bar` or whatever.  But that's fine: if your computer insists on storing a file named `bar` inside a directory/folder named `util` inside a directory/folder named `foo` when Git is storing a *file* named `foo/util/bar`, the *pattern* `*/util/*` matches Git's file name.

Note that `-x` only excludes *untracked* files, so it only affects `git ls-files` invocations that print the names of files found in the work-tree, not those that print the names of files found in the index.  Files stored in the index literally do have long names that may contain slashes, such as `dir/sub/file.ext`: the *index* has no ability to store directories / folders.  (This is *why* Git cannot store an empty directory.  Git builds new commits from whatever is in the index, and the index does not store directories, so Git cannot build a commit containing an empty directory.)

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about untracked files.  So really, `-x` is useless unless you include untracked files via `-o`?

Comment: @user1795832: pretty much, yes.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I wanted to exclude files from `ls-files` that match a pattern, is that possible?  Say I have two files, `foo/bar/util/baz/test.txt` and `foo/bar/util/qux/test.txt`, can I exclude them with a single exclusion pattern?

Comment: Well, `foo/bar/util/*/test.txt` would match both, but would also match `foo/bar/util/plugh/test.txt` as well. If that's what you want, that's good; if not, perhaps avoid the `*` glob match. Note also that you can use `**` to match zero or more component names here as (at least the documentation claims) the `-x` arguments are handled the same way as lines in `.gitignore` files.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753573/how-do-i-exclude-files-from-git-ls-files for how to exclude files

Comment: @user1795832: ah, I missed the idea that you were no longer asking about the `-x` option. Yes, for that, you need to use *pathspecs* (as shown in the linked Q&A).

Answer (score 1):

To make exclusion patterns work on tracked files, ask for excluded-and-tracked files and invert your patterns.

So if you want to list everything that's tracked and outside the `media` directory,

```
git ls-files -ix\* -x'!media/*'
```

which defaults to listing tracked files and matches that sequence of patterns.

To filter both tracked and untracked, `git ls-files -ocix\* -x'!media/*'`